# PHP Remove Duplicates from an array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I am having a bit of an issue with my PHP array. First thing they have arrays inside of this array and I am trying to remove duplicates. I did a print_r of my array and it printed out this....

```
Array (
   [0] => Array ( [creditfeeid] => 318 [client] => Test 1 [adjustment] => 444.00 [issuedate] => 2012-02-10 20:27:00 [isrecurring] => No [comment] => 444 [commission] => 17.76 )
   [1] => Array ( [creditfeeid] => 319 [client] => Test 1 [adjustment] => 333.00 [issuedate] => 2012-02-10 20:27:00 [isrecurring] => No [comment] => 333 [commission] => 9.99 )
   [2] => Array ( [creditfeeid] => 320 [client] => Test 1 [adjustment] => 111.00 [issuedate] => 2012-02-10 20:27:00 [isrecurring] => No [comment] => 111 [commission] => 1.11 )
   [3] => Array ( [creditfeeid] => 321 [client] => Test 1 [adjustment] => 222.00 [issuedate] => 2012-02-10 00:00:00 [isrecurring] => No [comment] => 111 [commission] => 2.22 )
   [4] => Array ( [creditfeeid] => 292 [client] => Test 1 [adjustment] => 555.00 [issuedate] => 2012-01-25 13:04:43 [isrecurring] => Yes [comment] => 555 [commission] => 5.00 )
   [5] => Array ( [creditfeeid] => 317 [client] => Test 2 [adjustment] => 666.00 [issuedate] => 2012-02-10 00:00:00 [isrecurring] => No [comment] => 666 [commission] => 39.96 )
)
```

I am trying to remove the duplicates in the ['comment'] which are

444
333
111
111
555
666

I have been working with unique_array and that doesn't seem to do the trick. This is what I have tried....

```
foreach($array as $row){
if(array_unique($row['comment'])){
    continue;
}else{
    echo $row['comment'] . "<br/>";
}
}
```

also

```
$array = array_unique($array);

foreach($array as $row){

        echo $row['comment'] . "<br/>";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is array_unique not the answer to my problem?

Thanks in advance,

J

Comment: which of the duplicates do you want to keep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

array_unique is not the answer to your problem. Instead, consider something like this:

```
$new_array = Array();
foreach($old_array as $a) {
    if( !isset($new_array[$a['comment']]))
        $new_array[$a['comment']] = $a;
}
$new_array = array_values($new_array);
```